# SyncAdapter not showing up in settings menu

Tags: android, service, synchronization, android-syncadapter

I am trying to setup SyncAdapter with google account. I did everything like in tutorials, but still my adapter is not visible in settings menu.

So here is my android manifest:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="pl.example.tasks"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="14"
    android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.AUTHENTICATE_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SYNC_SETTINGS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SYNC_SETTINGS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_CREDENTIALS" />

<application
    android:name=".TasksApplication"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >


    <service
        android:name="TasksSyncAdapterService"
        android:description="@string/tasks_sync_descr"
        android:exported="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/tasks_sync_label"
        android:process="@string/tasks_sync_process" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.content.SyncAdapter" />
        </intent-filter>

        <meta-data
            android:name="android.content.SyncAdapter"
            android:resource="@xml/taskssync" />
    </service>

    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <provider
        android:name=".TasksContentProvider"
        android:authorities="pl.example.tasks" />
</application>
```

and here is my taskssync.xml:

```
<sync-adapter xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:accountType="com.google"
    android:contentAuthority="pl.example.tasks"
    android:supportsUploading="false"
    android:userVisible="true" />
```

Please give me some guides what might be wrong here.

Answer (score 2):

I think you need the `android:syncable="true"` attribute in the provider node. So:

```
<provider
    android:name=".TasksContentProvider"
    android:authorities="pl.example.tasks"
    android:syncable="true" />
```

Comment: Alternatively, by code `ContentResolver.setIsSyncable(account, authority, 1);`